# WordPress Elementor how to make custom tabs?

Tags: wordpress, tabs, elementor

Here is the example [link](https://jimfahaddigital.com/service/i-will-design-or-develop-a-responsive-wordpress-blog-website/) and a [picture](https://prnt.sc/9zTPk0-pWDRp) of what I want. If anyone knows the process I request help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link https://wpjunction.net/elementor-show-hide-sections for this hope so it will help you :).